# How do I handle edge pixels from a image without any libraries but the standart ones from C++?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, blur, bmp

I have developed a code that can read and handle the bits from a 24 bits bmp image, mostly applying filters, but now I want to make my blur filter to blur the edge pixels too. Right now I have a 1 pixel edge, I'm using a 3x3 box blur, and this is the image I get after the blur is applied:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Px6Z.jpg

I'm able to keep the original bits from the image if I use an if statement in my inner loop but that doesn't really help given that I want it to be blurred and not the original unblurred bits.
Here is the code:

>

```
for (int count = 0; count < times; ++count) {
    for (int x = 1; x < H-1; ++x) {
        for (int y = 1; y < W-1; ++y) {
            double sum1 = 0;
            double sum2 = 0;
            double sum3 = 0;
            for (int k = -1; k <= 1; ++k) {
                for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j) {
                    sum1 += bits[((x - j) * W + (y - k)) * 3] * kernel[j + 1][k + 1];
                    sum2 += bits[((x - j) * W + (y - k)) * 3 + 1] * kernel[j + 1][k + 1];
                    sum3 += bits[((x - j) * W + (y - k)) * 3 + 2] * kernel[j + 1][k + 1];

                }
            }
            if (sum1 <= 0) sum1 = 0;
            if (sum1 >= 255) sum1 = 255;
            if (sum2 <= 0) sum2 = 0;
            if (sum2 >= 255) sum2 = 255;
            if (sum3 <= 0) sum3 = 0;
            if (sum3 >= 255) sum3 = 255;
            temp[(x * W + y) * 3] = sum1;
            temp[(x * W + y) * 3 + 1] = sum2;
            temp[(x * W + y) * 3 + 2] = sum3;

        }
    }
    bits = temp;
}
```

I know that 5 for loops nested are really slow but I would like to be able to make it work properly first, but if there are any tips on how to improve it I'm all ears.
Now as for the first loop, what it does is it applies the filter the amount of times you want.
The next two is to go through the vector as a 2d vector, and the inner 2 are for the box blur.

Important things to know: I have a vector of bits(RGB) and not just the pixels, that is why I treat them one by one(bits), also my vector is a 1d vector.

Comment: As you don't know what was beyond the bounds of the camera's field of view, everything you can do is basically just a *"reasonable guess"*. Some algorithms create black *"virtual pixels"* around the edge, some repeat the edge pixel out to the half-width of the kernel, some *"reflect"* the edge pixels going away from the edge.